# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no math in java.library.path

Tags: java

I am trying to run cpp code in java. but getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no math in java.library.path

I have tried to link my library to the `java.library.path` using this command after

```sh
$ javac HelloJNI.java

$ java -Djava.library.path="/home/sneha/Videos/node-ffi-example/math.so" HelloJNI
```

But still the same error.

Here is my `HelloJNI.java` file

```
public class HelloJNI {  // Save as HelloJNI.java
   static{

      System.loadLibrary("math"); // Load native library hello.dll (Windows) or libhello.so (Unixes)
                                   //  at runtime
                                   // This library contains a native method called sayHello()
      System.out.println(".so included");
   }

   // Declare an instance native method sayHello() which receives no parameter and returns void
   private native int num();

   // Test Driver
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     HelloJNI hj = new HelloJNI();
     int num = hj.num();  // Create an instance and invoke the native method
     System.out.println("Number: "+num);
   }
}
```

Please help, Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure to to use directory location:

```
-Djava.library.path="/home/sneha/Videos/node-ffi-example"
```

instead of

```
-Djava.library.path="/home/sneha/Videos/node-ffi-example/math.so"
```

Also, try using some sample that works out of the box to get familiar with `JNI`. For example: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-001/ or go directly to the sources: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo001

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, but getting same error after the change too.

Comment: Do you have your library file inside: /home/sneha/Videos/node-ffi-example/ - also, make sure to name your lib file following way: `libmath.so` - you can't have it as `math.so`. If you want to stick to `math.so`, change to `System.load("/home/sneha/Videos/node-ffi-example/math.so")`

Comment: Yes, tried using libmath.so but same error. Can you please tell me if we can use that so file directly, I mean Can we use cpp library directly in java and access the functions?

Comment: You have to create `JNI` wrapper anyway. Take a look here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-023/ or here http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-021/

Comment: Yes, thanks for the link, actually I am using swig to do it. [link here](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with swig, yet.

Comment: Please look at this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r7InAggais1XMIeHvF5tLZonWNaxIEDU/view?usp=sharing , I am not able to solve the error.

Comment: Now, it looks like you are calling: `System.loadLibrary("libmath")`. The rule here is. You have to call `System.loadLibrary("math")` but name of the file must be `libmath.so`.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you so much. Solve the problem :)

Comment: .oOo. Cool! .oOo. - have fun with JNI! :)

Answer (score 0):

try using a .dll instead.(that worked for me)

Comment: Hey, thanks for you reply! but I am using linux so using .so file.